# Ubutu Core 16 - Cannot login

Tags: ubuntu-core

I created my SSO credentials as requested to download the Ubuntu Core 16 image for Raspberry Pi3.
I downloaded the image and wrote it to the SD card. Boot the device from it, but as cannot login to the image running on the Pi3.
I tried @localhost and from another device on my network with:
ssh bert2694u@my-pi3-ipaddress
It asks me for the password, but the password is invalid, either if I just press enter or put in my UbuntuOne account password.

Please advise.
Thank you
Albertus de Wet